Flutter http.post issues when ran in IOS or Android but not Chrome
I am making a HTTP post method in one of my dart files, after having to remove an SDK (Backendless) as it was causing issues when trying to run on IOS Devices or desktop devices.
But I can run that code in Chrome and it works and responds to the app perfectly, I can even see it in the network inspector no issues in chrome.
When running in IOS or android simulator I get a 400 error. I am using HTTP post.
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'main.dart'; // Assuming HomePage is correctly defined in this import
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _attemptLogin() async {
    const String apiUrl = 'https://flashfriend.backendless.app/api/services/AccountAPI/Login';

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Email': _emailController.text.trim(),
      'Password': _passwordController.text.trim(),
    };

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: headers,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        await _saveUserSession(data);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );
      } else {
        _showSnackbar("Login failed: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _showSnackbar("An error occurred: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveUserSession(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('userToken', data['user-token']);
    await prefs.setString('userName', data['name']);
    await prefs.setString('userEmail', data['email']);
    await prefs.setString('userProfilePicUrl', data['profilePicture']);
  }

  void _showSnackbar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _attemptLogin,
              child: Text("Login"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}'''

I have tried hardcoding the details in, it works fine in postman screenshot also attached. I am hoping its a super simple issue that someone will be able to point me in the right direction of!

Many many thanks in advance.[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/OsOlB.png


can you show the full stacktrace? any more info apart from 400 error

did u add appropriate permissions to your files (AndroidManifest.xml) to access the internet?

somthing like this             
